# Retrieve DateTime objects from a certain string

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have the following string:

```
"23/09/2015 08:00\r\n            עד\r\n24/09/2015 08:00"
```

As you can see, we have two dates. One before the first `\r\n` and the other one after the second `\r\n`.

How can I retrieve `DateTime` objects from this string in C#? The only way I know is to use `Substring` but that retrieves the text after the first `\r\n`.

Comment: `string.IndexOf`, then `string.SubString`, then `DateTime.TryParse`

Comment: You can use string split method

Answer (score 3):

This may help

```
 var stringValue = "23/09/2015 08:00\r\n            עד\r\n24/09/2015 08:00";

 var splitted = stringValue.Split(new string[]{"\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 var firstStringDate = splitted[0];
 var secondStringDate = splitted[2];
```

And to get the `DateTime`:

```
var firstDate = DateTime.ParseExact(splitted[0], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
var secondDate = DateTime.ParseExact(splitted[2], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad I wrote exactly the same answer than you, but you were faster :)

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad When I'm using 14:00 as the hour it can't recognize the date. Why?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams I run this an it works, Are you sure the input string is exactly the same as the string that you provided here?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams if I remember well "hh" works for hours like AM/PM, "HH" works for the 24 hours format

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Yes. This is the string I'm using: `25/09/2015 08:00\r\n            עד\r\n25/09/2015 14:00`.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams yes as @codroipo  said you should use `HH` if you are using 24 hour style

Answer (score 1):

`Split` and `TryParse` the `string`s:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> extractDates(string inputString)
{
    foreach (var item in inputString.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(item, 
                                   "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                   out dt))
            yield return dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `myString.Split("\r\n")` like so:

```
string[] dates = myString.Split("\r\n");

foreach (var dateString in dates)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateTime))
    {
        //Use dateTime here
    }
}
```